# RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder() doesn't bind TextView from List to a ViewHolder

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, textview, listadapter

I have this RecyclerView Adapter which holds on to a List of View objects (TextViews and ImageViews)
I have a custom ViewHolder which have a TextView member data
Inside onBindViewHolder i am trying to bind the custom ViewHolder's TextView member data to a TextView from the List
The Log shows that the correct text right away, but after the callback has returned the default text "TextView" is printed to the screen
This is my class:

```
public class UnwantedRealityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    Context mContext;
    String habitPath;
    List<View> list;

    public UnwantedRealityAdapter(Context context, int id){
        mContext = context;
        habitPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/" + String.format("%05d",id) + ".txt";
        getFileToList();
    }

    /**
     * all file lines start with a digit that indicates what is the content of the line
     * 1 text
     * 2 image path
     */
    public void getFileToList() {
        // open the file to read
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(habitPath) );
            String line;
            TextView tv;
            ImageView imageView;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.charAt(0) == '1'){ // text
                    tv = new TextView(mContext);
                    tv.setText(line.substring(1));
                    list.add(tv);
                }
                else{
                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(line.substring(1))));
                    list.add(imageView);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(list.get(position) instanceof TextView)
            return 1;
        if(list.get(position) instanceof ImageView)
            return 2;

        return -1; // error
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch(viewType){
            case 1:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.text_item, parent, false);
                TextViewHolder textViewHolder = new TextViewHolder(view);
                return textViewHolder;
            case 2:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = new ImageViewHolder(view);
                return imageViewHolder;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch(viewType){
            case 1:  
                //THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
                ((TextViewHolder)holder).textView = (TextView) list.get(position);
                Log.i("===", "at position: "+ position + " text is: " + ((TextViewHolder)holder).textView.getText()); 
                // this log shows correct output
                   
                break;
            case 2:
                ((ImageViewHolder)holder).imageView = (ImageView) list.get(position);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public TextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the setText method:

```
((TextViewHolder)holder).textView.setText( ( (TextView) list.get(position) ).getText() );
```

please advise
why does the TextView pointer changing its value back againg after the callback had returned?

this is the what i am seeing:
[image]

and this is the what i want to see:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't "hold onto" list of views. Parse your input into String/Uris then use them to setText or setImage during onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Thank you. is it a bad practice to do this? why is it so?

Comment: You're violating pretty much entire concept of "recycling view" pattern which is to re-use same view between multiple items (during scroll).

Comment: why do you say that? i only change the value of the pointer. the same View Holder is still re-used as far as i can tell. what am i missing?

Comment: Modifying reference of viewholders textview does not alter its view hierarchy, original textview is already part of it. As for re-using, you don't seem to understand the part where recycler view will only create enough views to fill the viewport (for example 5) while you create view for all items immediately (even if your input ends up creating 1000 items).

Comment: OK thanks, i'll change it to a list of strings. is a String object is less expansive than a TextView object?